# Is there any alternative to string[]?

Tags: solidity, remix, etherscan

I need to store a number 4D security hashes. For example:

```
CCHdU3mFEYPpa-CYeDSooeZtYSG-CD9czobepa4a9-CRmVpX3Tegakr
```

I am storing number of these hashes in array of string i.e. string[] using

> `pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;`

I also need to view these in Etherscan by passing it as an event:

> event onSubmissionBoth(bytes32[] indexed docHash, string[] indexed
> doc4DHash);

```
function submitHash(bytes32[] calldata docHash,string[] calldata doc4DHash) external onlyOwner() {
       emit onSubmissionBoth(docHash,doc4DHash);
    }
```

The problem is I dont think the Etherscan supports the experimental string[]. As I get this when I decode the string[]

```
#b�r�����i��ZI�5�V������f%����
```

But bytes32[] works fine.

- Is there an alternative to String[] to view it in good form in Etherscan?
- Also if not, how should I implement the 4D hashes so that I get it in
  good form in Etherscan

Comment: Why do you need support from etherscan?

Comment: It is used so that one can verify the timestamp of the given hash through Etherscan.